# Root test for radius of convergence with negative numbers

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-2\right)^{n}+3^{n}}{n}x^{n} $$
I have to find the radius of convergence so I used the root test.
Found:
$$ \sqrt[n]{\left|x^{n}\right|\left|\frac{\left(-2\right)^{n}+3^{n}}{n}\right|}=\left|x\right|\sqrt[n]{\left|\left(-2\right)^{n}+3^{n}\right|} $$
Not exactly sure how to find the limit inside the absolute value.
For positive numbers $a>0,b>0 $I can just use the squeeze theorem:
$$ \sqrt[n]{max\left\{ a,b\right\} ^{n}}<\sqrt[n]{a^{n}+b^{n}}<\sqrt[n]{2max\left\{ a,b\right\} ^{n}} $$
How do I find the limit with negative values though?

Comment: Since $(-2)^n$ changes sign, it is sometimes positive, so it would be appropriate to use the squeeze theorem with the $\sqrt[n]{2\text{max}\{a,b\}^n}$ formula.

Comment: The equality$$ \sqrt[n]{\left|x^{n}\right|\left|\frac{\left(-2\right)^{n}+3^{n}}{n}\right|}=\left|x\right|\sqrt[n]{\left|\left(-2\right)^{n}+3^{n}\right|} $$is false.

Comment: You could note that $(-2)^n = \frac{(-2)^n}{3^n}\cdot 3^n > -\frac{1}{2}\cdot 3^n$ for big enough $n$ for example.

Comment: Is the above equality right for $ \lim_{n\to\infty} $ though?
And even when I use the squeeze theorem for the upper bound, what do I do about the lower bound?

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt[n]{(-2)^n+3^n}=3\sqrt[n]{(-2/3)^n+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$,

- if $n$ is even, $(-2)^n+3^n=2^n+3^n\in\left(3^n,2\times3^n\right)$;
- if $n$ is odd, $(-2)^n+3^n=3^n-2^n\in\left(\frac123^n,3^n\right)$.

So, in both cases, you have $(-2)^n+3^n\in\left(\frac123^n,2\times3^n\right)$. And therefore$$\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(-2)^n+3^n}nx^n\right|}\in\left(\sqrt[n]{\frac1{2n}}3|x|,\sqrt[n]{\frac2n}3|x|\right).$$Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac1{2n}}=1\quad\text{and}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac2n}=1,\quad$$you get that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(-2)^n+3^n}nx^n\right|}=3|x|$$and that therefore the radius of convergence is $\frac13$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that covers it completely.  
For future similar questions, is it enough to just take the Sup of the limits and skip the rest?

Comment: It works in every case and it is not hard to justify.